# jQuery Isotope limit number of elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Is it possible to limit the amount of entries in Isotope? Currently I'm adapting Isotope for a table-like data structure, and I'm adding dynamic sorting.

The way it goes - I have a set number of entries in HTML (10 for the time being). They are sorted by time added. When a user selects some sort of sorting, there is a possibility that there are other entries in the database that match the requested parameters, yet they are not loaded. So I use jQuery to insert the elements that match the users sort request

```
$.get('myfile.php?request=something', function(callback) {
    var $newItems = $(callback);
    $('.container').isotope( 'insert', $newItems );
    $('.container').isotope({ sortBy : USER_SORT });
});
```

All of it works perfectly, the only issue I have, is that I get more elements added (I wish to keep a set number of visible entries). I could do a workaround and limit the height of my container and set `overflow: hidden;`, but I'm also implementing vertical infinite scroll (when you scroll to the bottom more entries are added). So that would require constant managing of the container itself, and it seems to me like there should be a better way of doing this?

Another way would be adding the new elements, doing the sort, and then removing the unwanted entries from the bottom, but that would be awful, as the user will see additional data filtered and animated, and then removed.

So my question .. Is there a way to limit the entries within Isotope itself? Or maybe someone has a better idea of how to limit them?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `nth-child` CSS selector to limit the set of filtered results, e.g.

```
$grid.isotope({
    filter: ':nth-child(-n+10)'
});
```

This will show the first 10 results.

Comment: But this won't work properly if we use 'sortBy' option.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would add my two cents to this, as `:nth-child(-n+*)` wasn't suitable for my case. The reason being is that nth-child selects the elements in the order they appear in the DOM, so if your elements are in a random order it doesn't really work.

A less elegant way to solve this issue is to change the isotope instance's item selector to a class you add to the items you want to display, such as `.item-selected`, then add that class to the first `n` items in the `filteredItems` collection returned from the `arrangeComplete` callback. This is inelegant because it requires you to destroy and reinitialise your isotope container every time you filter it, but it works.